# How to test floating dialog boxes in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am practicing Cypress on the Facebook app. I am having an issue on testing these following scenarios:

1. When clicked on First Name, this floating dialog should be visible.
2. Validating the text in the dialog box to be 'What's your name?'.

```js
cy.get('input[name="firstname"]').focused().then(($txt)=>{
  cy.get('[data-testid="undefined"]>.uiContextualLayer uiContextualLayerLeft>._5v-0 _53im>#js_18n').should('be.visible').and('contain',"What's your name?");
});
```

But this is not working.

This is a pic of what I am testing:

[image: Facebook sign up page]

Comment: Side note: there are sites with intended purpose for automation practice. Definitely recommend those as oppose to a real site.

Comment: Can you suggest some websites for react testing using cypress

Comment: The live automation sites are mainly older tech. Github has plenty of react repos that you can fork and write cypress tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click()
cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click()
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click() //triggers the error message
cy.contains('What\'s your name?').should('be.visible')
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But I want to ask how we can normally check hover messages/ or these messages?

Comment: I think there is no easy way with facebook. You have to first manually see in the browser how the error message is replicated and  then create the same steps in your tests. Thats how I did it.

Comment: okay thank you for the amazing tip.

Answer (score 3):

The popup is added to the end of the page after clicking the red icon.

```js
cy.contains('div', 'First name')
  .parent()
  .next()    // red icon
  .click()
cy.contains('.uiContextualLayerPositioner', "What's you name?")
```

Comment: not working it is not finding the element

Comment: Sorry I missed a `.` on the class.